# Require_Once not Linking PHP Files on Server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, hosting

I have two PHP files located on my server. crpapi.php (http://www.nickrubin.byethost14.com/crpapi.php) and example.php (http://www.nickrubin.byethost14.com/example.php).

I am building an application using AJAX that posts an id value to example.php, which using crpapi.php, displays some information back to the user. As of now, I am having the AJAX post to "http://www.nickrubin.byethost14.com/example.php" - which works, and displays back some of the information I need. The problem is that the "require_once('crpapi.php')" command in the example.php file isn't working, and therefore not echoing information received from the crpapi.php file. Basically, the files aren't connecting for some reason. Maybe I have the wrong path?

Both files are located in the same directory on my server.

example.php

> require_once('crpapi.php');

Thanks for the help.

Comment: To help future requests, it is recommended that you accept an answer. Psst, little hint -- it gives you some reputation to accept an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is on the server, it may it may be the link to the file. So, if the file is in the folder `/api` and you're working from the root, consider `/api/crpapi.php`. Try enabling `error_reporting` to see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I ended up fixing the problem by simply combining them into a single php file.

Comment: In that case, it was most likely a linking issue. However, I am glad you've found a solution on yourself, nice work.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend use `set_include_path()` before `require_once()`

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(__DIR__ . '/..'),
    get_include_path()
)));
```

Sets the include_path configuration option for the duration of the script.